# Retornar valor de um request!

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou praticando um pouco de nodeJS, então decidi criar uma aplicação para a consulta de temperatura, porém me deparei com uma duvida. Como faço para retornar o valor da variável "weather":

```
const tempo = () =>{
    request(`http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/locale/city?name=Joinville&state=SC&token=${TOKEN}`, (error, response, body) =>{ 
        const id = JSON.parse(body)[0]["id"]
        request(`http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/locale/${id}/days/15?token=${TOKEN}`, (error,response, body) =>{
            const weather = JSON.parse(body)
        })
  })
}
```

Comment: `console.log(weather)` não retorna nada?

Comment: É importante que você não coloque em sua pergunta a imagem do código e sim o código em si, facilitando para quem possa vir a responder.

Comment: Então, sim o console.log(weather) funciona perfeitamente, porém queria tirar o valor do request pra fora do escopo da função. Claro, estou começando com o node em si agora, então não sei se isso é uma prática ruim, ou estou usando o node de forma errada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se por "retornar" você quer dizer "servir como uma resposta a um `endpoint`", você pode utilizar o `express` da seguinte forma:

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const app = express();

const TOKEN = '[SEU TOKEN]';

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await fetch(`http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/locale/city?name=Joinville&state=SC&token=${TOKEN}`);
    const { 0: { id } } = result.text();
    const body = await fetch(`http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/locale/${id}/days/15?token=${TOKEN}`);
    res.send(JSON.parse(body.text()));
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send('Ocorreu um erro interno.');
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('A aplicação está sendo executada na porta 3000!'));
```

A instalação do `express` na sua aplicação pode ser feita por meio do comando abaixo:

```
npm install express
```

E a instalação do módulo `node-fetch` pode ser feita por meio do comando:

```
npm install node-fetch
```

O serviço pode ser acessado por meio de:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

**Observação:** Como você forneceu uma imagem ao invés do código, podem ocorrer erros de digitação. É importante que você não coloque em sua pergunta a imagem do código e sim o código em si, facilitando para quem possa vir a responder.

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder. Então, acho que não me expressei bem, com "retornar" quis dizer tirar o resultado do escopo da função e tratar ele fora dela, porém como estou começando agora com node, não sei se é uma boa prática fazer isso, ou se até mesmo estou usando de forma errada. Quero fazer isso para jogar o resultado para o HTML/CSS posteriormente.